# Prove there is a sequence in $x_n$ in $A$ with $x_n \rightarrow x$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $A \subset X$. Let $x \in \overline{A}-A$. 
Prove there is a sequence in $x_n$ in $A$ with $x_n \rightarrow x$.

---

I am not sure how to even start this. I am not good at building sequences. Any hints would be helpful as so I can start to write something up. Even the first line would help or maybe what the goal is.

$\textbf{Convergent sequence:}$ $x_n \rightarrow x$ means $\forall \, \text{open} \, U \subset X$ with $x \in U \,\, \exists N$ such that $x_n \in U \,\, \forall n \geq N$.

Comment: Try a particular example. Let's say, $X$ is $\Bbb R$, $A=(0,1)$ and $x=0$. How would you find a sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $B(x, 1/n) \cap A \not = \emptyset$. So there is a $x_n \in B(x, 1/n) \cap A$ for every  $n \in \mathbb{N}$. I will leave it to you to check that the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ works.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $\bar A-A\subseteq\partial A$, where $\partial A$ is the boundary of $A$. From there, you can use the definition of the boundary to prove the existence of the sequence.